# Date format and validity in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to code on SQL server to get the format first of the date and then convert it to dd/mm/yy format. After which I also need to check if the date is valid most specially in cases such as say for example 06-07-2015. How will I know the format of that one (if it is June 7 or July 6) and convert it to dd/mm/yy. I also need to check if the year is valid meaning the date should be less than the current year. Including date in February must not be greater than 28 except if it's a leap year. Can you please help me improve my codes? Thank you so much!

```
       set language 'us_english'

       SET DATEFORMAT dmy
       CREATE TABLE [sample].[dbo].[EY_LFA111](
                 [MANDT] [nvarchar] (255) NULL,
                 [LIFNR] [nvarchar] (255) NULL,
                 [ERDAT] [date] NULL,
                 [ERNAM] [nvarchar] (255) NULL,
                 [MENGE] [float] NULL,
                 [WKURS] [decimal] (30,15) NULL,
                 [CPUTM] [time] NULL
        )
       insert into [sample].[dbo].[EY_LFA111](
                 [MANDT],
                 [LIFNR],
                 [ERDAT],
                 [ERNAM],
                 [MENGE],
                 [WKURS],
                 [CPUTM]
        ) 
     select
           LTRIM(RTRIM([MANDT])),
           LTRIM(RTRIM([LIFNR])),
           case 
              when ISDATE(LTRIM(RTRIM([ERDAT]))) = 1
                 AND ERDAT LIKE '[0-3][0-9].[0-1][0-9].[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
              then LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(date,[ERDAT], 103)))
           else NULL end,
           LTRIM(RTRIM([ERNAM])),
           LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(float,[MENGE]))),
           LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(decimal(30,15),[WKURS]))),
              case when ISDATE(LTRIM(RTRIM([CPUTM]))) = 1
                 then LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(time,[CPUTM], 108)))
               else NULL end
       from [sample].[dbo].[EY_Formatted$]
```

Comment: If you're in SQL Server 2012 or newer try_parse might help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this. A lot of unnecessary code was removed and the validation has been improved. This answer will work in sqlserver-2012+

```
INSERT [sample].[dbo].[EY_LFA111](
            [MANDT],
            [LIFNR],
            [ERDAT],
            [ERNAM],
            [MENGE],
            [WKURS],
            [CPUTM]) 
SELECT
    LTRIM(RTRIM([MANDT])),
    LTRIM(RTRIM([LIFNR])),
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date, [ERDAT], 103) < GETDATE()
        THEN CONVERT(date,[ERDAT], 103)
        ELSE NULL end,
    LTRIM(RTRIM([ERNAM])),
    TRY_CONVERT(float,[MENGE]),
    TRY_CONVERT(decimal(30,15),[WKURS])),
    TRY_CONVERT(time, [CPUTM])
FROM [sample].[dbo].[EY_Formatted$]
```

Comment: Hi, t-clausen.dk. I'm using SQL Server 2008 RTM and the codes didn't work. TRY_CONVERT is not even recognized as a built-in function name. Any help with this, please?

Comment: Hi, t-clausen.dk. I'm using SQL Server 2008 RTM and the codes didn't work. TRY_CONVERT is not even recognized as a built-in function name. Any help with this, please?